# (-6x^2-x-7)(2x^3+3x^2-2x-5) as input in SymPy

Tags: python, scipy, latex, sympy, tex

Is there any function in SymPy can take thisexpression as an input

```
(-6x^2-x-7)(2x^3+3x^2-2x-5)
```

to find the derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a variety of parsers in the **`parsing`** module.

There may be a better way, but this works:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import standard_transformations,               \
                                       implicit_multiplication_application

transformations = (standard_transformations + ( implicit_multiplication_application, ) )

>>> var('x')
x

>>> s = '(-6x^2-x-7)(2x^3+3x^2-2x-5)'
>>> parse_expr( s.replace( "^", "**" ), transformations = transformations )
(-6*x**2 - x - 7)*(2*x**3 + 3*x**2 - 2*x - 5)

>>> _.diff(x)
(-12*x - 1)*(2*x**3 + 3*x**2 - 2*x - 5) + (-6*x**2 - x - 7)*(6*x**2 + 6*x - 2)
```

But I see that a rule in the **`mathematica`** parser just needs a tweak and then you can do this as:

```
from sympy.parsing.mathematica import mathematica as M
from sympy.abc import x

M( '(-6x^2-x-7)(2x^3+3x^2-2x-5)' ).diff(x)
```

the **`mathematica`** parser gives error

```
from sympy.parsing.mathematica import mathematica as M
from sympy.abc import x

M( '(-6x^2-x-7)(2x^3+3x^2-2x-5)' ).diff(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\sympify.py", line 313, in sympify
expr = parse_expr(a, local_dict=locals, transformations=transformations, evaluate=evaluate)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 757, in parse_expr
return eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 691, in eval_expr
code, global_dict, local_dict)  # take local objects in preference
File "<string>", line 1
(-Integer (6 )Symbol ('x' )**Integer (2 )-Symbol ('x' )-Integer (7 ))*(Integer (2 )*Symbol ('x' )**Integer (3 )+Integer (3 )*Symbol ('x' )**Integer (2 )-Integer (2 )*Symbol ('x' )-Integer (5 ))
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
M('(-6x^2-x-7)(2x^3+3x^2-2x-5)').diff(x)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\mathematica.py", line 8, in mathematica
return sympify(parse(s))
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\sympify.py", line 315, in sympify
raise SympifyError('could not parse %r' % a, exc)
sympy.core.sympify.SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse '(-6x**2-x-7)*(2*x**3+3*x**2-2*x-5)'' failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

Comment: the mathematica parser seems good ,but here it only gives out error ,have you tried it ?

Comment: `parse_expr` is definitely your best bet here.

Comment: Is there any way to simplify (-12*x - 1)*(2*x**3 + 3*x**2 - 2*x - 5) + (-6*x**2 - x - 7)*(6*x**2 + 6*x - 2) ？ I want to get the final result ,not an intermediate one.